# Crontab error: no crontab For [user]

Tags: cron

I'm seeing an error every time I do the command below. Why?

```
$crontab -l
no crontab for server
```

where *server* is the user account.

This issue comes about because the script in crontab doesn't work, so I've tried to break down the problem. This is what I have put in using `crontab -e`:

```
crontab -e
@reboot /usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
```

I press ctrl + o and save it, reboot and find the script doesn't boot (even though the script itself does work if I double click it from the GUI). If I do a `crontab -l` after the reboot, I find I get the same error as above. Even before the reboot, if I try and open the `crontab -e` just after I saved this command inside of the file, the line of code isn't there.

Comment: This may help: https://superuser.com/questions/359580/error-adding-cronjobs-in-mac-os-x-lion My problem was resolved.

Answer (score 36):

That's probably because this user does not have a crontab, yet. You can create a crontab for this user by calling:

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Ok I will update my question with some more info about my problem. Please, I beg you so much to help me fix it.

Comment: Ok I have updated my question to be more specific to the problem I'm facing. See if you can help. I'm really struggling here.

Comment: mac users see: https://superuser.com/a/540693/928461

Comment: Thank you, I thought I could just go into the terminal and write a command and it will get automatically added to the crontab without having the need to create it. Your answer helped put things into perspective.

Answer (score 8):

If you get the message "No crontab for username" type the following:

```
sudo crontab -u username -e
```

You will be asked to select an editor from a menu. Then a default file will open.

Save the file without naming it.

To check that the file was successfully created type:

```
crontab -l
```

Answer (score 3):

The user **server** does not have any schedule job in **crontab** so ***crontab -l*** outputs that information, not an error.
Normally, you can find a user's crontab file in directory **/var/spool/cron/crontabs**.

Comment: The reason it doesn't is because I can't make a job in that file that it remembers. I've updated my post, please check it now.

Comment: After adding job to crontab, what is the result of **crontab -l**? @johnsmith

Comment: Hi I have fixed this now. It turns out the actual root cause of the problem was that I was using ctrl+z to close nano (sends process to background) rather than ctrl+x, so the cron job was not installing.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a silly mistake, I was setting up a cron using `sudo` and then running the `crontab -l` without sudo, so I was setting up the cros on root a/c and checking on the user's account due to which it was not finding the crons which were set up.

When I ran `sudo crontab -l` it gave me all the crons which had been set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Oracle Linux) it was complaining about the absence of files under /tmp/
It turned out that the folder was removed earlier.
After creating /tmp again - it works like a charm. I hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score -1):

**Here's the syntax or example for given problem:**

```
`root@tacktile-desktop:/home/tacktile/Downloads# (crontab -u root -l ; echo "*/2 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf") | crontab -u root -`
```

`root@tacktile-desktop:/home/tacktile/Downloads# crontab -l */5 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf */5 * * * * //usr/bin/bash /usr/binaries/scripts/tomcatlogs.sh */5 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /usr/binaries/scripts/tomcatlogs.sh */5 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf */2 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score -3):

Your crontab not run. You need to run your command on the root with 4 steps:

```
Step 1: crontab -e
Step 2: o (o in alphabet)
Step 3: Fill your command. Ex: */2 * * * * root /usr/local/auto/restart.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 
Step 4: Exit
```

> ESC
>       :wq
>       Enter

```
Review your CMD –> crontab -l . It was saved here(/var/spool/cron)
```

Source: https://thuthuatcaidat.com/sua-loi-no-crontab-for-root/

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question since author ot the question already performed these steps